# How to make a book or report with a huge amount of Images?

Tags: c#, sql-server, vb.net, reporting-services, printing

A couple of years ago I was ask to make a very specific inventory app for a house. So I made it in Vb.net and C# and made a MS SQL Server 2008 r2 datebase to save all the items. Every item has his own picture and they are categorized by families like, appliances, licours, etc...

The clients were very happy with the app, so every time that they wants to make a change they call me and I do it. This time they want me to make some type of report functionality. They want to make a book for each family, the amout of items in every familie is between 800 and 1300 so I make a report server and a I was able to make every report, every report is more than 850mb because all the images, but they want an elegant design and the report designer of VS is very rigid.

Someone know other tool to make reports with a better design or an other method where I can render all the data of a database to make a book that I can design and print and export(optional)?

Thanks!

Comment: I guess you can go for Sql Server Reporting Services. If you want go for better design templates then there are many third party tools available.

Comment: PDF comes to mind; there are several PDF libraries around you can use with .NET and C#; you'll need to check the license models, though..

Comment: Hi! Thanks for answer! @sdeep I'm alredy using sql server Repoting Services, can you mention some of these tools?

Comment: @TaW thanks I will search those pdf libreries and make some research! I will comment these when I get result!

Comment: Its been a while but I have found these to be not half bad:[PDFsharp & MigraDoc](http://www.pdfsharp.net) and [iText](http://itextpdf.com/). Also look at this [old post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/373926/lightweight-open-source-pdf-library-in-c) with some discussions..!

Comment: Thanks @TaW I wil take a look and let you know later

Comment: You should also research ways to reduce the size of the images in your book.

Comment: Hi! @lrb Actually didn't thik about it but in all the experimentation I find Crystal Reports! That It very dynamic with the design and optimizes the picture so it allow me to export the book(report) between 160 and 250 mb... But now I have a new problem it doesn't give me the option to fit proportional the image so it displayed bad... Do you guys have some suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Every one! The only solution that I get is to make a Report with Crystal reports that is so much dynamic and is so much easier